# Access vba adOpenStatic

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was looking at the documentation for adOpenStatic which says:

> Uses a static cursor. A static copy of a set of records that you can
> use to find data or generate reports. Additions, changes, or deletions
> by other users are not visible.

I am trying to understand what this means. Is this saying that when we open an `adOpenStatic` recordset and try to perform some operation like reading, editing etc, changes made by other users from the time we open this recordset to the time we close the recordset is not visisble. So if any other user changes the same record while we are trying to change it will it use the what ever was the last change?

Comment: Yes it is a snapshot, don't use it for anything that will be modified use a dynamic setting instead.

Comment: It's a read-only recordset. You will see records up to the time you executed the query